# Expectation through survival function

Tags: random-variables, expectation

I understand how we get $$E[x] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x)) dx$$ but why does this apply only to non-negative random variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the integral, and integrate partially:
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^0 1-F(x)\,dx=\left[ x(1-F(x)) \right]_{-\infty}^0+\int\limits_{-\infty}^0 xf(x)\,dx$$
In this formula on the right side, if $X\in L^1$ the integral is finite, but the change of the product is infinite. Informally 
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty 1-F(x)\,dx=\infty + EX $$

Comment: But $-\int_{-\infty}^0 F(x) \,dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 xf(x)\, dx$.

Answer (score 0):

For negative number we have:

$E(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{0}sf(s)ds = -\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_s^0 dx f(s)ds = -\int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{-\infty}^x f(s)ds dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{0} F(s) ds $

The theorem I used here is the Fubini's theorem, just be careful about the order of integration.